# Ant - If condition / and-or

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I was wondering if it  was possible to make something like that in Ant (v1.9.4):
if((a=1 or a=2) and (b=3)) then ...

I tried

```
<ac:if>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${aa}" arg2=""/>
            <not>
                <isset property="a"/>
            </not>
        </or>
        <and>
            <contains string="${b}" substring="${c}" casesensitive="false"/>
        </and>
        <then>
            <property name="b" value="true" />
        </then>
</ac:if>
```

But I got than error while running it...

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/), you must have a single condition under the `if` task as shown below (you cannot have both `<or>` and `<and>`). You also don't need to check if the property is set as it is semantically covered when comparing the property to a value with `equals`:

```
<if>
    <and>
        <or>
            <equals arg1="${a}" arg2="1" />
            <equals arg1="${a}" arg2="2" />
        </or>
        <equals arg1="${b}" arg2="3" />
    </and>
    <then>
        <!-- do stuff -->
    </then>
    <else>
        <!-- do other stuff -->
    </else>
</if>
```